# ¿Cuál es el verbo correspondiente a "inmerso"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, verbos, adjetivos, participio

De vez en cuando me cruzo con textos como éste:

> Especialmente significativo resulta el ambiente de tranquilidad en el que **se ha inmerso** el líder y candidato...

Normalmente, "inmerso" lo suelo ver usado como adjetivo: *está inmerso*, *se encuentra inmerso*... Pero aquí se usa como verbo.

En el DLE, si busco `inmerso`, solo aparece esto:

> [**inmerso, sa**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=LeZAIC6)
>   Del lat. *immersus*, part. pas. de *immergĕre* 'sumergir'.
>
> 1. adj. Sumergido en algo. U. t. en sent. fig.

**¿A qué verbo corresponde "inmerso" en la cita inicial? ¿Es correcto este uso?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Según el *Diccionario nacional de la lengua española* de don Ramón Joaquín Domínguez de 1853:

> **Inmergir**, v.a. Sumergir, introducir algún sólido en un líquido, hasta que este lo cubra perfectamente, retirándolo en seguida.

También recoge *inmergirse*. La acción de este verbo es *inmersión*, y el que inmerge es un *inmersor*. Este verbo también se recoge en el *Zerolo* de 1895 (que establece su etimología en el latín *immergere*), el *Toro y Gómez* de 1901, el *Alemany y Bolufer* de 1917 y el *Rodríguez Navas* de 1918. Las únicas apariciones por parte de la RAE son en los *Academia Manual* de 1927 y 1950, con la siguiente definición:

> ***INMERGIR**. tr. Neologismo inútil por sumergir.

Este verbo no se recoge únicamente para explicar de dónde viene *inmerso*. Existen algunos casos (pocos) de su uso:

> *Se compone de una serie de barrotes muy aproximados, y de mucha altura que inmergen en cierta extension, en el agua al objeto de tenerlos frios en parte, y evitar su pronta destruccion.*
>
> Juan A. Molinas, "Tratado de maquinaria y de aparatos industriales", c1885 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *El interesante episodio referido por Binondo inmergió al Oficial de mar en mayores cavilaciones y tristezas.*
>
> Benito Pérez Galdós, "La vuelta al mundo en la Numancia", 1906 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *Transcurridos uno o dos minutos de desarrollo, se encenderá la linterna rojo-obscura para cercioramos del estado de la imagen, y en caso de que el vigor sea insuficiente, se inmergirá nuevamente la placa en el baño, teniendo la precaución de apagar la linterna o, mejor, de proteger la cubeta con un tape de cartón.*
>
> Santiago Ramón y Cajal, "La fotografía de los colores. Fundamentos científicos y reglas prácticas", 1912 (España).

Si te lo estás preguntando, sí, la mayoría de los textos que contienen este verbo (usado principalmente con su participio regular: *inmergido*) son tratados científicos.

Sobre la idoneidad de su uso, entiendo que *inmerso* es el participio irregular del verbo (como *impreso*), por lo que la construcción es válida, si bien usa un verbo que la RAE califica de "inútil". Yo propondría el uso de la palabra como adjetivo más que como participio, así:

> En el que se halla inmerso...
>   En el que está inmerso...
>   En el que se encuentra inmerso...

Por lo que he podido ver, el motivo por el que tenemos *sumergir* pero no *inmergir* es que el verbo *[immergo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=immergo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)* en latín se usaba mayormente en poesía, así que debía ser una palabra culta y, por tanto, tenía menos posibilidades de que el pueblo llano la siguiera usando con el paso de los siglos. En todo caso, [he preguntado en el sitio de latín](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/9355/2646) a ver qué me cuentan.

Comment: El portugués tiene el verbo "imergir" y el italiano tiene el verbo "immergere", que seguramente tienen la misma raiz latina "immergo". Si la razón que el verbo "inmergir" no existe en español fuera que ese verbo se usaba mayormente en poesía y no por el pueblo llano en latín, me parece que lo mismo habría pasado en portugués y italiano. Creo que esa teoría no es válida.