# ¿Cuál es el verbo correspondiente a "suficiente"?

Tags: verbos, solicitud-de-término, adjetivos

En la respuesta a *[¿Queda actualmente algún caso en el que el participio de presente se use como verbo?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/27834/12637)* vimos que hay algunos participios de presente usados como adverbios o preposiciones, además de los correspondientes adjetivos y sustantivos. Normalmente es fácil saber de qué verbo viene la forma, como *bastante* que viene de *bastar*. Sin embargo, en otros casos no queda claro, así que siguiendo la senda iniciada con *[¿Cual es el verbo correspondiente a "inmerso"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28970/12637)*, que nos deparó una sorpresa, me animo con la siguiente pregunta.

Dada la voz *suficiente*:

> **[suficiente](https://dle.rae.es/?id=YehIeT0)**
>
> Del lat. *sufficiens, -entis*.
>
> 1. adj. Bastante para lo que se necesita.
> 2. adj. Apto o idóneo.
> 3. adj. Pedante, engreído que habla con afectación.

¿De qué verbo proviene? Imagino que será de un verbo que existió en su día en latín, pero ¿llegó ese verbo a ser usado en algún momento en el idioma español? ¿O tal vez algún derivado del mismo? Y si es así, ¿qué significado tenía?

Comment: el _suffice_ inglés! WordReference [recomienda](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=suffice) _bastar_ o _satisfacer_ como posibles verbos equivalentes, pero no veo ninguno que tenga la misma raíz.

Comment: @fedorqui sí, me acordaba del inglés _suffice_. Pensé que en español igual existió en algún momento un _suficiar_ o algo así.

Comment: El inglés *suffice* viene del md. francés *souffire*, y parece que no hay ningún otro verbo de la misma raíz latina en las otras lenguas románicas. Es una historia similar con ej. el gallego [*devecer*](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/devecer), descendido de *dēficiō* pero sin cognados en castellano etc.

Comment: En francés: suffir. Además, cuando uno está harto de alguién que habla demasiado o está diciendo barbaridades, se dice: Ça suffit!' :) Pero también en el sentido de ser lo suficiente como para x. être suffisant pour x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tras buscar un rato en el CORDE palabras comenzadas por *sufic-, sufec-, suffic-, suffec-*, que serían posibles raíces del hipotético verbo castellano correspondiente al latín *sufficere*, no encontré nada salvo textos propiamente latinos o bien la palabra *suficiente(s)* o su variante ortográfica antigua con *-ff-*, además de un par de instancias de *sufecto* (del supino *suffectus*) con un significado técnico poco claro. De esto deduzco que el verbo en cuestión nunca existió en castellano.

Puestos a imaginar, podemos pensar cómo habría evolucionado tal verbo. *Sufficere* proviene de *sub-* + *facere*, con asimilación /b/ > /f/ entre el prefijo y la raíz original y una alternancia /a/ > /i/ sumamente común en latín. De esta raíz alternada *fic-* derivan muchos otros verbos latinos y llamativamente ninguno tiene un cognado "directo" en castellano, es decir, en ningún caso tenemos un cambio regular y directo como el de *facere* > *hacer*. Generalmente encontramos un cognado del supino, terminado en *-fectum*, que en castellano pasa a *-fecto*: *afecto*, *efecto*, *perfecto*, etc. (de *afficere*, *efficere*, *perficere*, respectivamente). Sobre ese descendiente del supino se vuelve a derivar en castellano, como con *afectar* y *efectuar*. Otras veces en el mismo latín se deriva un sustantivo sobre la misma raíz en *-e-* del supino y el castellano deriva un verbo sobre él (*perfectiōnis* > *perfección* > *perfeccionar*, *cōnfectiō* > *confección* > *confeccionar*).

Los cognados modernos con *-ct-* son todos cultismos o semicultismos, ya que este grupo de consonantes dio normalmente *ch* /tʃ/ en castellano; hay un caso donde además de darse esta evolución regular una /f/ corta intervocálica se sonoriza: *prōfectum* (de *prōficere*) da *provecho* y de ahí deriva *aprovechar*.

Siguiendo estos modelos, de *sufficere* podríamos tener, hipotéticamente, los siguientes cognados en castellano (teniendo en cuenta que la /u/, fuera de los cultismos y de la influencia de la vocal alta /i/, podría o debería dar /o/):

- **sufectar*
- **sufectuar*
- **sufechar* o **suvechar*
- **sofechar* o **sovechar*
- **sufeccionar*

Comment: Buscando en el CORDE también se encuentran bastantes casos de _sufiçiente_ y _sufiçiençia_. Pero como dices, no encontré ni rastro alguno de un posible verbo.

Comment: Esta respuesta es brutal, ofrezco recompensa para mostrar mi agradecimiento, que hago extensiva a multitud de otras respuestas tuyas. ¡Gracias por tanto, Pablo!

Comment: Muchas gracias por la apreciación, @fedorqui. Me ruborizo. :)